# Dynamic Label and Button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

How to create dynamic label and button in flex 3?

Comment: There are a lot of possible answers for this.  Can you provide some context please?  In what situation are you trying to create a dynamic label?  Are you just looking to change the label of a button based on some other variable value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function yourFunction():void
{
   var tmpLbl:Label = new Label();
   tmpLbl.x = 10;
   tmpLbl.y = 5;
   tmpLbl.text = "Label Text";

   yourObj.addChild(tmpLbl);  // where yourObj is the object you want to add the label to
}
```

Pretty much the same deal for a button except the buttons text would be set with btn.Label

To add an onclick event just use

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ...
```